# Any way to set multiple keys and values at once in Maya using python?

Tags: python, maya

I'm looking for a solution, that allows to set list of values

```
[0,1,2]
```

over given list of times

```
[0,1,2]
```

at once, without loop, like this:

```
for frame, value in zip([0,1,2], [0,1,2]):
    cmds.keyframe(node, e=True, vc=value, t=frame)
```

There are commands

```
cmds.setKeyframe()
```

and

```
cmds.keyframe()
```

that allow to set animation keys at a given time 
But non of them allow to set range of value over the range of time (frames).

The same value can be put on the time range, but that's not the case.

```
mel.eval("setKeyframe -e -v %s -t 0 -t 1 -t 2 %s" % (value, node))
```

I tried to get attributes of the animation curve node, that stores keys inside,
but got an empty output.

```
node = '...'
types = cmds.listAttr(node)

for t in types:
    if cmds.objExists(node+t):
        try:
            print t, cmds.getAttr(node+t)
        except:
            print 'failed with', t
            continue

...
keyTimeValue [()]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest approach does not work in 2019 Maya.
For those who will stumble upon, here is the proper code.

```
def add_keys(plugName, times, values, changeCache=None):
    # Get the plug to be animated.
    sel = om.MSelectionList()
    sel.add(plugName)
    plug = om.MPlug()
    sel.getPlug(0, plug)
    # Create the animCurve.
    animfn = oma.MFnAnimCurve(plug)
    timeArray = om.MTimeArray()
    valueArray = om.MDoubleArray()

    for i in range(len(times)):
        timeArray.append(om.MTime(times[i], om.MTime.uiUnit()))
        valueArray.append(values[i])
    # Add the keys to the animCurve.
    animfn.addKeys(
        timeArray,
        valueArray,
        oma.MFnAnimCurve.kTangentGlobal,
        oma.MFnAnimCurve.kTangentGlobal,
        False,
        changeCache)
```

Comment: I have a question. After running that command, can you **undo** the action? I can't find a way to undo it, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.
Here is a documentation about anim curve node.
https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Nodes/animCurveUU.html

You can see, the keyTimeValue attribute stores no data by itself.
But its attributes keyTimeValue.keyTime and keyTimeValue.keyValue do.

This command worked as I expected:

```
def keyframe_range(node, values, id_range):

    eval("cmds.setAttr('%s.ktv[%s].kv', %s, size=%s)" % (
        node, id_range, ','.join([str(v) for v in values]), str(len(values))))

selected_id = cmds.keyframe(sl=True, query=True, iv=True)
index_range = '%s:%s' % (str(selected_id[0]), str(selected_id[-1]))
selected_curve = cmds.keyframe(query=True, name=True)
keyframe_range(selected_curve[0], values, index_range)
```

But there is a limit up to 255 arguments in Python 2.7 a function can get.
As soon, as the values are feeded direct to the function,
no more, than 255 keys can be processed at a time.

Comment: your command doesn't work here : # RuntimeError: setAttr: The attribute 'pSphere1_translateX.keyTimeValue[0].keyValue' should be set with the keyframe or setKeyframe command. #. Anyway if it works for you, i guess it is fine !

Comment: I'm using Maya 2015.

Comment: Maybe they change something on maya 2018